# Is this a 2-cyclic cocycle ? Does it have a nontrivial geometric interpretation?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, noncommutative-geometry, surfaces, differential-forms

Let $S$ be a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Inspired by the $2$-cyclic cocycle defined in page 20 of the book ["Non-commutative geometry" by Alain Connes](http://www.alainconnes.org/docs/book94bigpdf.pdf), we consider the  following $3$-linear map on the space $\Omega^2(S)$ of $2$-forms on $S$:
$$\tau(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=\int_S ({*\alpha}) (d^* \beta)(d^* \gamma).$$

> Is this $3$-linear map a $2$-cyclic cocycle?
>
> What do we obtain from this quantity if we put $\alpha={*f}$, $\beta ={*g}$, and $\gamma={*h}$, where $(f,g,h):S \to \mathbb{S}^2$ is the Gauss normal map?

Note that the space of $2$-forms has a structure of algebra via the isomorphism $*:\Omega^0(S)\to \Omega^2(S)$.